# Atomically update multiple volatile and j.u.c.atomic variables

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, atomic, volatile

In order to atomically update two and more volatile variables does it need to be guarded by lock with synchronized, reentrantReadWriteLock etc?

i.e.

```
volatile int vVar1, vVar1; // or AtomicInteger

/*** Needs to be updated atomically ***/
void atomicUpdate(int var1, int var2){
  vVar1 = var1;
  vVar2 = var2;
}
```

The same code is for java.util.concurrent.atomic variables.

Comment: SHort answer, yes, now that seems to be a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info), so why don't you take a step back and tell us what you want to do?

Comment: I want to update my two variables atomically in multithreaded envairement.

Comment: I said to take a step back. The fact that you have two `volatile` variables indicates that there seems to be a problem with your underlying design. Hence my advice to take a step back and tell us what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, volatile guarantees visibility and establish happens before relationship between a var write and its subsequent read. It doesn't have anything to do with atomicity of operations on two different memory locations.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to assign two values atomically, chaning `volatile int` to `AtomicInteger` will not solve your race condition problem.

To solve your issue, you basically have two options:

1. Make the methods updating the variables `synchronized` (and maybe the methods reading those variables too)
2. Create an wrapper for your two variables, and make use of the fact that assignment is an atomic operation

Example for option 2:

```
volatile Vars vars;
void atomicUpdate(int var1, int var2) {
    vars = new Vars(var1, var2);
}

public static Vars {
    private int vVar1;  // volatile if they need to be modified
    private int vVar2;
}
```

I largely prefer option 2 since it is non blocking and allows you to *cache* any type of data.

Comment: Re: "...and maybe the methods reading those variables too..."  No.  Not _maybe_.  Synchronizing only the code that _updates_ the variables will do _nothing_ to protect other code from _viewing_ them in an inconsistent state.

Comment: It depends on how the variables are read. If they are never read together, it does not matter ;-)

Comment: Your option 2 has the same problem that wha'eve's answer has:  It's only half a solution.  You can "atomically" assign a new object reference to `vars`, but that doesn't do anything to protect another thread that first looks at `vars.vVar1` and then looks at `vars.vVar2`.

Comment: Again, it depends on the reading part. If you do: ``Vars vars = c.getVars(); int v1 = vars.getV1(); int v2 = vars.getV2()``, you are all good, even though ``vars`` in ``c`` might have been replaced.

Comment: "Again it depends on the reading part..."  That's why I called it "half a solution"  The reading part is the other half of the solution.  You haven't given the noob a whole solution until you give him both halves.  That was kind of my point about the need to synchronize the reading threads as well as the writing threads.  To assume that there _is_ no reading thread that cares about the relationship (whatever it is) between the two variables is to assume a special case.  But if you don't know that the special case is valid, then should tell the noob about the general case.

Answer (score 3):

Create a Class which encapsulates all of your state variables, then use [AtomicReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) to refer to them.  This alleviates race conditions where a thread needs to set/check multiple values safely.

```
// set initial state
AtomicReference<MyState> ref = new AtomicReference<MyState>();
ref.set(new MyState("abc", "def"));

// .. Thread 1 needs to change the state:
ref.set(new MyState("xyz", "def"));

// .. Thread 2 needs to read the state (consistently):
MyState state = ref.get();
if ("test1".equals(state.a)) { }
else if ("test2".equals(state.b) { }
```

The benefit here is that `Thread 2` is able to read `MyState.a` and `MyState.b` consistently from the same `MyState` instance, as opposed to having the `MyState` instance variable it's referencing change in-between checks.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to update my two variables atomically

You can't.  There are no atomic operations in the Java language or in the Java standard library that span more than one variable.

You can probably solve your problem using the `synchronized` keyword, but using `synchronized` is different from using atomics because, in order for it to work, the threads must *cooperate* with one another.

If there is a specific relationship that must always exist between those two variables (a.k.a., an *invariant*), and if you can't update the variables without temporarily *breaking the invariant*, then you must synchronize the code that does the update, and you must also synchronize *every other block of code that expects the invariant to be true.*

That's because, when you write this:

```
synchronized(foo) { ... }
```

It doesn't prevent other threads from doing anything except synchronizing on the same object at the same time.

---

Also note:  Once you have properly synchronized all access to the variables, then you won't need them to be `volatile`.  That's because whatever one thread writes to memory before releasing a lock is guaranteed to become visible to any other thread that subsequently acquires the same lock.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use a volatile array:

```
private volatile int[] var;

void update (int var1, int var2) {
  var = new int[] { var1, var2 };
}
```

that would be atomic but it assumes that the rest of your code does not access vVar1 and vVar2 directly. There may be better options depending on what you are trying to achieve - for example you could create an ad hoc thread safe holder class (typically immutable) for the two ints.

Comment: What if code in some other thread examines `var[0]`, and then examines `var[1]`?  And what if, in between those two operations, the first thread "atomically" updates `var` (i.e., sets it to point to a new array)?  You've only given half of a solution.  The other half is where the second thread stashes its own, local reference to the array, and _only then_ examines its two members.

Comment: @jameslarge obviously - hence my comment about code external to the class not having access to the array itself. But whether examining the two variables atomically is required depends on the op's use case. BTW Jean Logeart's answer does essentially the same thing except that the two ints are wrapped in a class instead of an array.